# zend framework 2 default routing action change url to default action

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i thought i had the routing under control until i found out that i have now clue of how to have the default action url change, that means:
when ever a user enters a url, for example:

> http://www.mysite.com/form/myform

the routing will always redirect him to the default action "show" (one of many actions this controller has):

> http://www.mysite.com/form/myform/show

but my url remains the same (with the "show" action):

> http://www.mysite.com/form/myform

what am i missing here?

```
        'routes' => array(
        'form' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/form[/:form[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'form'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Form\Controller\Form',
                    'action'     => 'show',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

thanks!

**edited note:**

i have noticed (thanks to @codeHeart marks) that i had some mistakes/misclarification trying to explain the problem, so i edited the main question examples.

thanks again all!

Comment: It seems its all ok in your router configuration. Is there any redirections in controller code?

Comment: there is a redirection in the code, that happens only if the user had logged in:
'$this->redirect()->toRoute('form',array('form' =>$this->form->id, 'action' => 'status')'

Comment: Is it full router configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this in your question/

```
http://www.mysite.com/controller
```

and your router configuration I expect that should be throwing a 404 error, as there is no matching route in your config that matches /controller(If there are more routes other than the one that you show in you question, let us know or maybe you mistyped this url).

Apart from above,

your route tells to do the following:-
if url is

```
 http://yoursite/form OR

 http://yoursite/form/controller
```

go to the controller action that you have mentioned in the defaults, as the route was matched to the url but didn't get matched completely to an action so going to the default.
A non existing controller or a non existing action should be throwing 404. e.g

```
 http://yoursite/form/controller/non-existing-action
```

Even this url

```
http://yoursite/form/
```

won't get matched according to your route and will be throwing a 404.

And for your question if you want to change the default action to something other then the "show" action, simply change the action parameter/key in defaults

```
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Form\Controller\Form',
            'action'     => 'some-other-action',
        ),
```

Hope this helps and sorry if I was of no help.

Comment: you are right, i had some misclarification with my question. i have edited my main question due to that, hope you could take a look at this again. --thanks!

Comment: @amitben Hey! were you able to solve your problem? The default action controller can be changed as mentioned in the answer